# referencing like nature journal

Tags: bibliographies

Journals such as Nature use a specific format of citations.

> currently they can only follow a few genes simultaneously7
>
> 7. Locke, J. C. W. & Elowitz, M. B. Using movies to analyse gene circuit dynamics in single cells. Nature Rev. Microbiol. 7, 383–392
>    (2009).

In the text, there is a small number similar to a footnote for citation. However the list of references are not shown as a footnote, instead this list will be at the end of the document (like a regular bibliography).

How can we create such a style in LaTeX? It seems it should be a common format, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: package `biblatex` provides the autocite mechanism that lets you choose *supercripts*.

Comment: by the way, hi and welcome. If leaving a thanks note is appropriate is discussed controversial within our community, but *Thanks bros* might be a bit too informal. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
I know a great book\autocite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: mgoriBiblatexNature]

Comment: @Mgorji [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)